# Sorting database column values returned from query as a numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

**Issue**: I am writing a query that involves a count() operation on a column but returns the count in the string format. As a result the sorting on the front end is messed up.

**Details:**
I am writing the following query in Zend:

```
$select = $this->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('s' => 'student'),
            array('s.id', 
            'start_date' => new Zend_Db_Expr("date(s.start_date)"), 
            ))
        ->joinLeft(array('ps' => 'pstudent'), 
                's.id = ps.st_id',
                array('pscount' => new Zend_Db_Expr('count(ps.st_id)')  ))
        ->where('ps.status = "phd"');

$result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

This query returns me the `pscount` by using the `Zend_Db_Expr (count(ps.st_id))`.
At a later point in code I encode this data to json format and return to the front end.
Since the data from db comes as a string (ie `pscount` is a string), when I sort on the front end on `pscount` column of the grid, I get the following sequence.

**1

10

100

11

12

13**

However,I want it to sort by numeric value so the output is:

**1

10

11

12

13

100**

I tried writing the `Zend_Db_Expr` as `new Zend_Db_Expr('cast(count(ps.study_id) as signed)')` but there is no change in the results.
I cannot use an ***order by*** in the query as well due to application requirements.
The only other option is if I traverse through the `$result` and then do a `(int)` type conversion in php code. However that is the last option. 
**I would prefer to do this in mysql query so that I do not have to traverse through the results unnecessarily.**

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just get it as an array of strings and use `sort($someArray, SORT_NUMERIC)`.  This will sort them as if they were numbers.

If you need to sort complex objects, use usort() with a comparison function.

I don't believe you can order results inside mysql without using `order by`.

Comment: I do not want to use order by in the mysql query, because the sorting is controlled from the front end. So I need to send the data to the front end as numeric and not strings.